# CNTK: How to define UpSampling2D

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, cntk

I'm wondering how to achieve UpSampling2D in CNTK. I cannot find such layer in the [API](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs).

UpSampling2D is an opposite operation of pooling layers, and expand the data by repeating the rows and columns of the data. Here's keras/tensorflow API for [UpSampling2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/layers/UpSampling2D).

By looking at the [tensorflow code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L1069), they use `backend.resize_images` operation, but I cannot find resize operation in [CNTK API](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs) either.

[image: UpSampling2D]

## Answer 1 (From Frank)

[image]

## Answer 2 (From David)

[image]

[Picture from Quora: How do fully convolutional networks upsample their coarse output?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-fully-convolutional-networks-upsample-their-coarse-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be assembled from basic operations of reshaping and splicing, e.g.

```
>>> x = Input((3, 480, 640))
>>> xr = reshape(x, (3, 480, 1, 640, 1))
>>> xr.shape
(3, 480, 1, 640, 1)
>>> xx = splice(xr, xr, axis=-1) # axis=-1 refers to the last axis
>>> xx.shape
(3, 480, 1, 640, 2)
>>> xy = splice(xx, xx, axis=-3) # axis=-3 refers to the middle axis
>>> xy.shape
(3, 480, 2, 640, 2)
>>> r = reshape(xy, (3, 480*2, 640*2))
>>> r.shape
(3, 960, 1280)
```

Comment: Actually, with version 2.0 of CNTK/Python (on Azure Notebook), I got this error: TypeError: splice() got multiple values for argument 'axis'. Need to do like this C.splice((xr, xr), axis=-1)

Comment: @Frank Seide I tried this in CNTK C#. The dimensions doubled, but the image content isn't upsampled. Instead it's just 4 times the original image next to each other. 
How could splicing upsample the content of the image?